# Video control using Vimeo API

Tags: javascript, video, vimeo, video-player, froogaloop

I have a vimeo JavaScript here, could someone tell me if it would be possible get the vimeo video to go to start once finished;

Here is the code I have so far using JavaScript

```
// JavaScript Document

var animSpeed = 400;

function onPlay(id) {
jQuery('.blankOverlay').fadeIn(animSpeed);
jQuery('h2').text('You clicked play!');
}

function onPause(id) {

jQuery('.blankOverlay').fadeOut(animSpeed);
jQuery('h2').text('The video is paused.');
}

function onFinish(id) {
jQuery('.blankOverlay').fadeOut(animSpeed);
jQuery('h2').text('The video has now finished.');
}


jQuery(function($) {
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// --------------------------------------------- PHYSICIAN INDIVIDUAL PAGES --
/* ----- video player api (vimeo) ----- */
var iframe = $('#vplayer')[0],
player = $f(iframe);

// When the player is ready, add listeners for play, pause, finish, and playProgress
player.addEvent('ready', function() {

player.addEvent('play', onPlay);
player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);

});

$('.introContent, iframe').click(function(){    $('.blankOverlay').fadeIn(animSpeed); });
$('.blankOverlay').click(function(){ $(this).fadeOut(animSpeed);  player.api('pause'); });

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `player.api('play');` in the `finish` event handler.

Something like this

```
player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);

function onFinish(){
  player.api('play'); // this should take the video to the start again
}
```

If you want to just take the video back to initial state you can use

```
player.api('unload'); // this should take the video to initial state but will not automatically start
```

Here is a [updated demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPKeyM?editors=001) and here is the [reference](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api#methods) for more methods.

### Update

1. Variable `player` is defined inside a function and being accessed from outside
2. Event handler `onPlayProgress` is not defined at all for which an error is thrown.

***[Here is an updated demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yymmeG)***

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you please update the demo from my answer with your piece code ?

Comment: Updated my answer please check

Comment: Is there a function in the api to goto the start but without playing, almost get it ready to play again?

Comment: I can think of two options: `player.api('seekTo', 0)` or `player.api('unload');` Not complete sure if they'll work. But give it a shot.